# What does this extra pair of parentheses do?

Tags: c, if-statement, parentheses

While looking into a piece of code, I saw this line:

```
if ((b = a)) { /* statements */ }
```

Reading the context, I know its intention is like this:

```
b = a;
if (b != 0) { /* statements */ }
```

I know the two lines above can be simplified into the first code block, but why are the two pair of parentheses? Wouldn't that seem redundant? I think this is totally OK:

```
if (b = a) { /* statements */ }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually one do that to avoid the warning from the compiler, that the assignment is to be (then) evaluated as a condition (in case the developer missed an `=` in `==`)

> warning: suggest parentheses around assignment used as truth value

Something more indicative,

```
int c = !!(b = a); // condition

if (!!(b = a)) {
```